# Replace Arbitrary Numbers of Word

Tags: sed

Using `sed`, I want to replace patterns in the following way:

```
---          >>>         +++
--+--        >>>         ++-++
--+-+--      >>>         ++-+-++
--+-+-+--    >>>         ++-+-+-++

...

--(+-)^n-    >>>         ++(-+)^n+
```

The string, which I am operating on is an arbitrary list of +'s and -'s.

```
--+++-+--+--++-+--++--+-+--++--+-++-+-
```

I tried this, but it doesn't do the job.

```
sed '/--\<+-\>*-/{s/+/A/g;s/-/+/g;s/A/-/g}'
```

For the above example, I'd expect the following output:

```
--+++-+--+--++-+--++--+-+--++--+-++-+-     (input)
--+++-+++-++++-+--++++-+-++++--+-++-+-     (output)
       !!!!!        !!!!!!!
```

(The exclamations marks indicate the changed regions.)

Comment: It looks like you are swapping- and +. Try swapping all - for X, then all + for -, then all X for +

Comment: That's what I did. The problem is not the replacing procedure, but the pattern matching.

Comment: Your line selector, `/--\<+-\>*-/` won't match. Remove it and your `sed` will swap +/- because your substitution RE is correct.

Comment: Your sample doesn't match your description. For your description: `perl -pe 's/--(\+-)*-/$& =~ y|-+|+-|r/ge'`

Comment: Sorry, I just inverted the process in the example. I'll quickly fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the perl command. It seems to work. But I was trying to do it with sed.

Comment: i cant understand why only some pluses and minuses are swapped in your last output example but all of the others seem to alternate in all of the rest? can you explain that? you might be able to do it with `sed`, but you'll need to describe to what you want done a little better. at least i dont get it.

Comment: I want to search and replace patterns of the kind `--(+-)^n-`. They are supposed to get replaced by the exact same pattern, only with +'s and -'s inverted. Please, tell me if I am blind and there are more patterns like this in my example, but I can find only two of them (`--+--` and `--+-+--`).

Answer (score 0):

You try to modify just the part matched by the regex in your address, but once the address matches, the substitution affects the whole line. The trick is to only have what you want to change in the pattern space when you apply the transform. This command does it:

```
sed '/--\(+-\)*-/{:a;h;s/.*\(--\(+-\)*-\).*/\1/;y/+-/-+/;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)--\(+-\)*-\(.*\)/\2\1\4/;/--\(+-\)*-/ba}' <<< '--+++-+--+--++-+--++--+-+--++--+-++-+-'
```

I *little bit* easier to read:

```
/--\(+-\)*-/ {                  # Match a line containing the pattern
    :start                      # Label to branch back to
    h                           # Copy pattern space to hold space
    s/.*\(--\(+-\)*-\).*/\1/    # Remove everything but pattern
    y/+-/-+/                    # Swap + and -
    G                           # Append hold space to pattern space
    s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)--\(+-\)*-\(.*\)/\2\1\4/  # Rearrange pattern space
    /--\(+-\)*-/b start         # If there are more occurrences, branch to start
}
```

Notice that this probably won't work with the comments, `y` seems to have a problem with them.

Testing with example string:

```
$ sed -f sedscr <<< '--+++-+--+--++-+--++--+-+--++--+-++-+-'
--+++-+++-++++-+--++++-+-++++--+-++-+-
```

Two points to mention about the sed command in the question:

- `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries, but you just want grouping: `\(\)`
- If you have a direct mapping of characters to change, you can use the transform command `y` instead of multiple substitutions